# msdb system table fragmentation

Tags: index, ola-hallengren

I have a Index Maintenance job for msdb database to rebuild those fragmented index in msdb database.

But I still found some backup related table in msdb database (e.g. backupmediafamily, backupset, backupfile) has high fragmantation.

After further checked found out it was skipped by the Ola Index maintenance command.

My question is how I can make ola defragment the index rather than I write another set of index maintenance just for msdb ?

Comment: Welcome to DBA.SE and thanks for participating. How many pages in the table? If <1000 pages, then Ola's script won't trigger. What defaults are you using? What is the job definition? Add more details to your question via the [edit] link.

Comment: more than 1000 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is those tables in msdb  (e.g. backupmediafamily, backupset, backupfile) 
are MS Shipped Object. by default, Ola skip those MS Shipped object for rebuild/reorganize.

MS Shipped Object means the objects that are created by internal SQL Server components.

Solution: Add 1 more parameter @MSShippedObjects = 'Y' to enable the Ola command to get those MS Shipped Object to defragment.